# Change save location of Tiddlywiki when using Download Saver

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I am currently using Tiddlywiki as it comes, i.e. from the folder `Downloads\tiddlywikilocations\index.html`. It works flawlessly to save the file in the browser if it is located in exactly this folder, but it seems not possible to either rename the `tiddlywikilocations`folder or move it out of the `Downloads`folder.

How can I achieve this? I couldn't find any further information about this on the wiki itself. Ideally, I would like to use Tiddlywiki from a custom folder in another folder, without otherwise affecting the standard download behavior in Firefox (where to save files etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[Timimi extension](https://github.com/ibnishak/Timimi) for Firefox looks like what you need.

> you can save the standalone TW from anywhere in your harddrive without any more interactions